# redirect loop error in login page

Tags: php, sql

I am going from vulnerable SQL codes into secure one, and I am trying to update my login to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
        if($username != '' && $password!=''){
            session_start();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=? and password =?";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

            $stmt=bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $num->$stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->close();
            if($num>0){
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

            header("Location:homepage.php");
            die();

            } else {
                $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
            }
    }
}
```

When I am launching my login page I got this message:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>   Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
homepage code:

```
<?php
require_once ('/include/global.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Clinic Form</title>
<link href="css/1140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container12">
  <header>
    <div class="row" align="center">
      <div class="column12"> <a href="homepage.php"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center">
      <div class="row" align="center"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <h1 id="home" align="center">&nbsp;</h1>
  <div class="alert"></div>
  <div class="column12" align="center">
    <div class="row"><a href="patients.php">
      <input type="image" value="Patient" src="images/patient.png" width="widthInPixels" height="heightInPixels" onmouseover="this.src='images/patient_roll.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/patient.png';">
      </a> </div>
    <div class="row"><a href="/clinic form/appoint/appoint.php">
      <input type="image" value="Appointments" src="images/appointments.png" width="widthInPixels" height="heightInPixels" onmouseover="this.src='images/appointments_roll.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/appointments.png';">
      </a> </div>
    <div class="row"><a href="/clinic form/med/med.php">
      <input type="image" value="Medicaments" src="images/med.png" width="widthInPixels" height="heightInPixels" onmouseover="this.src='images/med_roll.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/med.png';">
      </a> </div>
    <div class="row"><a href="">
      <input type="image" value="Statistics" src="images/stat.png" width="widthInPixels" height="heightInPixels" onmouseover="this.src='images/stat_roll.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/stat.png';">
      </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

global.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 
//if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
//header("location:index.html");
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo "Page seen only by " . $_SESSION['username']."<br>";
  $con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);

}
else{
    session_destroy();
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

**EDIT 3**

The entire index.php code:

```
<?php

require_once('/include/global.php');

/*if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    if($_POST['username'] != '' && $_POST['password']!=''){
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start();
        session_register('username'); 
    } 

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
        $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if(is_array($row)) {
            $_SESSION["username"] = $row[$_POST["username"]];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];

            header("Location:homepage.php");
            } else {
            $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
        }

}else{
    $error_msg="Please fill all the fields";
}
}*/

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
        if($username != '' && $password!=''){
        session_start();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=? and password =?";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

            $stmt=bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $num->$stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->close();
            if($num>0){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("Location: homepage.php") ; die();
            } else {
                $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
            }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Clinic Form</title>
<link href="css/1140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container12">
  <header>
    <div class="row" align="center">
      <div class="column12"> <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a> </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <h1 id="home" align="center">Login</h1>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <?php if(isset($message)) echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>" ?>
    <div class="alert">
      <?php if(isset($error_msg)) echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$error_msg');</script>" ?>
    </div>
    <div class="column12" align="center">
      <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username"  />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="password" class="large-fld" name="password" value="" placeholder="*****"  />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="image" name="login" value="Login" src="images/btn.png" width="widthInPixels" height="heightInPixels" onMouseOver="this.src='images/rollOverBtn.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='images/btn.png';">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that when you find an existing user you don't do anything... then you redirect to the same page and you don't do anything again... and so on...

Comment: post code of `homepage.php` file too

Comment: I think you should add `homepage.php` source code. Then, when you check that the user sent the right credentials, you should authorize him, assigning some `$_SESSION` variabile to remember his access across different requests

Comment: guys my homepage is a simple html buttons but anyway see my edited code

Comment: @Saty still waiting your help with Diego too

Comment: Have you use any `header("Location:...");` in `global.php` file

Comment: I will post my global .php file

Comment: have you tried to call die(); after header(...);

Comment: No use of `globle.php file` in `homepage.php` just remove it `<?php
require_once ('/include/global.php');
?>` and check

Comment: it help me to take username as a session, so I need it in the next page that goes from homepage.php

Comment: how to use die after header @JRsz

Comment: @Saty I tried to remove the use of the file but still got the same error

Comment: @am90 header("Location: homepage.php"); die();

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will help you, if you be more specific about your header. When I started I found this little peace of code and use it ever since.

```
$hostname = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$path = dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

header("Location: https://".$hostname.($path == "/" ? "" : $path)."/homepage.php");
die();
```

But I have another question, where do you set your Session Variable $_SESSION["username"] ?

**EDIT:**

Ok, your code does this:

You call homepage.php which includes global.php. Since there are no session variables set yet, global.php jumps into this part

```
else
{
    session_destroy();
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

Here you redirect to index.php. In index.php you include global.php again and exactly at this point your loop begins. So your global.php sends you to index.php in which global sends you to index.php and so on.

On way is to simply remove the include of global.php at the very beginning of your index.php.

Further you need to call

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
```

instead of

```
$stmt=bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
```

Comment: do you call session_start() anywhere? I had some issues if I did not call session_start() everytime I used this array, but that is some time ago.

Comment: Ok, So your global.php file redirects you to the index.php, since there is no Session variable username set yet. Can you add the index.php as well? I suppose there is another header() call to homepage.php

Comment: then it is not flagged as it. I assume then that it is the first part of code? If so is this the entire code or are there other parts?

Comment: it is easy, when I hit the login button I want to go from index.php into homepage.php that's it, and in the vulnerable code it was working correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94484/discussion-between-jrsz-and-am90).

Answer (score 0):

Please add space in header function after Location: .

```
header("Location: homepage.php");
```

Comment: @am90 - ok, but you need to keep this space. Could you please post more details about your code or tell me which link is posting data to php code.

Comment: why I should keep the space ?

Comment: @am90 - For space please check php manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php .  And from above answer I think your issue resolved :)